# Which settings file does PreferenceFragment read/write?

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can I control which file should be used by a `PreferencesFragment` for reading and writing settings? I can't find anything about that in the docs. If that can't be controlled via code or XML resources, are there any guarantees, what the file is called, so I can open it explicitly using

```
Activity.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may be useful for copying the preference file after writing to it http://stackoverflow.com/a/25585711/1815624

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to manipulate the `PreferenceManager` of the `SettingsFragment`. This is what it looks like

```
// Constants
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private final static String TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getName();
public final static String SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = TAG + ".SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME";

// Life-cycle
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

    // Define the settings file to use by this settings fragment
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Then you can access this settings file outside of the fragment like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
        SettingsFragment.SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, I had to define the settings file in the `onCreatePreferences`method (instead of in onCreate) for it to work.