# Shared Preferences loading multiple values

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I currently am saving usernames and passwords in different shared preferences files. I want to load every value saved in the XML file, not just the first. How would this be written?

Comment: `SharedPreferences.getAll()` is that it?

Comment: To copy the file see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25585711/1815624

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is the following:

```
//if you are running the code inside from an Activity
Context context = this;
SharedPreferences userSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("USER_NAME_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences pwdSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PWD_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The method getAll() will return a data structure called `HashMap` which works  like a dictionary:

For each **value** stored there is a **unique key**.

sidenote: By getting them all at once you are kinda breaking the purpose of this data structure but let's continue

```
    Map<String, String> userNameHashMap = (Map<String, String>)userSharedPrefs.getAll();
    Map<String, String> pwdHashMap = (Map<String, String>)pwdSharedPrefs.getAll();
```

then you can do whatever you want with them

want them in a list? (I am assuming your user names are strings by the way)

```
    List<String> userNameList = new LinkedList<>();
    userNameList.addAll(userNameHashMap.values());
```

want to know if there's a password for user john?

```
    boolean johnHasPasswd = pwdHashMap.containsKey("john");
    String johnsPass;

    if(johnHasPasswd)
        johnsPass = pwdHashMap.get("john");
```

Comment: @Ferr0283 have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as correct , let me know if this helped =)