# Android: Cannot write SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

after a lot of research i finally decided to post the following issue here.
For a college project I want to save my app settings through SharedPreferences.
However whatever I do it doesn't work.

For a simple test I tried to write some testdata in my main activity's oncreate-method like this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Test", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("Test", true);
    editor.commit();
```

When I inspect the prefs object in debug mode it shows me the path where the file is supposed to be created: /data/user/0/.../shared_prefs/Test.xml

However when I navigate there on my phone it is not there.

I am using a Galaxy S6 with Android version 7 as a test device and
I have to add that I am a complete beginner at Android programming.
Could you point me into a direction here?

Answer (score 0):

> From Android Studio , start Android Device Monitor, go to File Explorer, and browse "/data/data/< name of your package >/shared_prefs/". You will find the XML there... and also you can copy it for inspection.
>
> If you have a non-rooted device it's not possible to do that directly from Android Studio. However, you can access the file with adb shell as long as your application is the debug version.

```
adb shell
run-as your.app.id`
chmod 777 shared_prefs/your.app.id_preferences.xml
exit # return to default user
cp /data/data/your.app.id/shared_prefs/your.app.id_preferences.xml /sdcard
```

> After that you can pull the file from /sdcard directory with adb.

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585711/1370087)

Comment: If you find yourself saying, "As already answered [here]", that's a sign that you need to flag this question as a duplicate, not answer it. In the future, please do that.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advice.