# Converting a normal Shared Preference to Encrypted Shared Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app is currently using

```
sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

to get the sharedpreference object.
Due to some security requirements, now I need to upgrade this to use EncryptedSharedPreference provided in the android jetpack library.

What happens here is when I use **EncryptedSharedPreference** object I loose all the data stored in normal shared preference file.
 How can I get all my data on the **EncryptedSharedPreferences**.

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148729/how-to-secure-android-shared-preferences

Comment: That is how I have implemented it now, but how can I upgrade for existing without losing the existing data.

Comment: How can it be? See https://medium.com/att-israel/how-to-migrate-to-encrypted-shared-preferences-cc4105c03518. If use the same file for `SharedPreference` and `EncryptedSharedPreference`, new data will be accumulated, not clearing previous.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer:**

My migration looks like this:

```
fun migrate() {
    val oldPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val newPreferences =  EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(...)
    with(newPreferences.edit()) {
        oldPreferences.all.forEach { (key, value) ->
            when (value) {
                is Boolean -> putBoolean(key, value)
                is Float -> putFloat(key, value)
                is String -> putString(key, value)
                is Int -> putInt(key, value)
                is Long -> putLong(key, value)
                is Set<*> -> putStringSet(key, value.map { it.toString() }.toSet())
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("unsupported type for shared preferences migration")
            }
        }
        apply()
    }
    oldPreferences.edit().clear().apply()
}
```

It is possible to do this without creating new shared preferences file, but why would you...

**Explanation:**

Any shared preferences are stored in an `.xml` file. You can [find the file and read it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352741), so it's not that hard to see what is happening with it.

I've tried to use `EncryptedSharedPreferences` with existing file and old values remained unencrypted. And `EncryptedSharedPreferences` are not able to access old values now.

`EncryptedSharedPreferences` are not encrypting the file. They encrypt keys and values separately, so your preferences.xml file might look like this:

```
<map>
    <string name="__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__">12a9018b0938...</string>
    <string name="AWNywuPwU...">ARu2fgn5N7wV...</string>
    <string name="__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset__">1288018cc6...</string>
</map>
```

This means you cannot run some oneliner to encrypt existing file. So I believe the only way is to make your own migration as shown in answer.

Hope it helps

Comment: did you encounter any performance issue during app start-up?