# Android Settings : How to use SharedPreferences in a SettingsFragment?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, settings, android-preferences

I am using my own SharedPreferences in a normal Activity with a custom layout with two checkboxes and seekbars. Now I want to make a proper SettingsActivity/SettingsFragment with these settings.
Is there a way to use my custom SharedPreference instead of the PreferenceManager and the default preference file?

My own preferecne:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.settingTimetable), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995236/3691378

> You have to manipulate the PreferenceManager of the SettingsFragment.
>   This is what it looks like

```
// Constants
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
private final static String TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getName();
public final static String SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = TAG + ".SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME";

// Life-cycle
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

    // Define the settings file to use by this settings fragment
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

> Then you can access this settings file outside of the fragment like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
        SettingsFragment.SETTINGS_SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```